# serializing object using gson and getting LazyInitializationException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, gson

This is my Controller method, i am trying to read my database by providing zip, cityname and province name.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/retrieve", method = RequestMethod.GET)

public @ResponseBody String retrieveObjectThroughAjax(ModelMap model){

 //Calling Service Method to read data according to zip,cityName and province provide

 PropertyItems propertyItems=getPropertyTypeandAddressService.readAddressFromZip("H2H-      
                              2N3","Montreal","Quebec");

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = null;
        try{

            json = gson.toJson(propertyItems); // serializing object

        }catch(Exception e){
            logger.error(Constants.METHOD_INSIDE_MESSAGE +"getAuthors",e);

        }
        logger.debug(json);
        return json;
    }

    }
```

**Service Method**

```
@Service
public class GetPropertyTypeandAddressServiceImpl implements GetPropertyTypeandAddressService{

    @Autowired
    private GetPropertyTypeandAddressDAO getPropertyTypeandAddressDAO;

    @Transactional
    public PropertyItems readAddressFromZip(String zipCode,String cityName,String provinceName){
        PropertyItems propertyItems=getPropertyTypeandAddressDAO.getAddressFromZip(zipCode, cityName, provinceName);
        Hibernate.initialize(propertyItems);
        return propertyItems;

    }
}
```

**DAO Method**

```
@Repository
public class GetPropertyTypeandAddressDAOimp implements GetPropertyTypeandAddressDAO{
    @Autowired 
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public PropertyItems getAddressFromZip(String zipCode,String cityName,String provinceName) {
        PropertyItems propertyitems = new PropertyItems();
          Criteria criteria = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(PropertyItems.class,"propertyItemsClass");
          if(zipCode != null){
           criteria.createAlias("propertyItemsClass.address","address");
           criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("address.zip",zipCode));
          List<PropertyItems> propertyitem = criteria.list();
          if(propertyitem.size()>0){
              propertyitems  =  propertyitem.get(0);       
           }
          }
          else if(cityName != null){
               criteria.createAlias("propertyItemsClass.address","address");
               criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("address.city","city"));
               criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("city.cityname",cityName));
               List<PropertyItems> propertyitem = criteria.list();
                  if(propertyitem.size()>0){
                      propertyitems  =  propertyitem.get(0);       
                   } 
              }
          else if(provinceName != null){
              criteria.createAlias("propertyItemsClass.address","address");
               criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("address.city","city"));
               criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("city.provinces","provinces"));
               criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("provinces.provinceName",provinceName));
               List<PropertyItems> propertyitem = criteria.list();
                  if(propertyitem.size()>0){
                      propertyitems  =  propertyitem.get(0);       
                   }

              }
        return propertyitems;
    }
}
```

**Console Error**

```
09:53:56,988 ERROR HelloController:567 - Inside Method: getAuthors org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.agilemaple.common.entity.Property.propertyType, no session or session was closed
at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:383)
at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationExceptionIfNotConnected(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:375)
```

As requested my Property Items Look like this

**Entity:
Propert Items**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="web_property_item")
public class PropertyItems {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="property_type_id")
    private PropertyType propertyType;


    @OneToOne(mappedBy="propertyItems",cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private Address address;



    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public PropertyType getPropertyType() {
        return propertyType;
    }

    public void setPropertyType(PropertyType propertyType) {
        this.propertyType = propertyType;
    }

    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(Address address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
```

**Entity : Property Type**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="web_property_type")
public class PropertyType {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="property_id")
    private Property property;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,mappedBy="propertyType", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<PropertyItems> propertyItems;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Property getProperty() {
        return property;
    }

    public void setProperty(Property property) {
        this.property = property;
    }

    public Set<PropertyItems> getPropertyItems() {
        return propertyItems;
    }

    public void setPropertyItems(Set<PropertyItems> propertyItems) {
        this.propertyItems = propertyItems;
    }

}
```

Comment: What does `PropertyItems` look like? Take note that `Hibernate.initialize()` does not cascade, so if you have lazily loaded properties further down the object graph, they will not be loaded and will of course cause the `LazyInitializationException` when accessed

Comment: i added PropertyItems in my question.

Comment: post pls code of PropertyType class

Comment: I uploaded PropertyType class

Comment: Check the first comment, it explains pretty good why you have LazyInitializationException. You have lazy collection on the PropertyType class.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in hibernate. Your field Set of properties has Lazy fetch method, it means that it will try to get when you call method get of this set. When u calling tojson methods, gson calls all get methods of object but in this moment hibernate session is close and hibernate can't open it in controller. I've faced with the same problem but directly on JSP. In a three weeks i resolved it by one more property for hibernate ( in your case) and I write code to opening session in view interceptor. I'm underground just right now, so I can't show property, but in a hour I will edit this answer and add property.

Added: 
I remembered ! property is: `hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans = true`

If it won't help, I will add code of opensessioninviewinterceptor.

```
@Override
public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    OpenSessionInViewInterceptor sessionInViewInterceptor = new OpenSessionInViewInterceptor();
    sessionInViewInterceptor.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory());
}
```

Comment: I remembered, added it.

Comment: Add entity where you have method getAuthors

Comment: Add entity where you have method getAuthor? what you mean by that?

Thats the exception be catched. If you see my post

 catch(Exception e){
            logger.error(Constants.METHOD_INSIDE_MESSAGE +"getAuthors",e);

Comment: try snippet of adding interceptors in web app config